# Getters/Setters for Python Class

Tags: python, dictionary, encapsulation, setter, getter

So I am working on setting up a Python class that is to be used as a way to get/set parts of a dictionary.  I'm trying to set it up so that I have a dictionary (for example ID Numbers : Names) and a variable that is the currently selected member of the dictionary.

I am trying to implement it so that I have getters and setters to return what the currently selected dictionary value is, as well as setters with a try/except block to change the current selection to another member in the dictionary.  I don't care about passing the ID Number, I just need to make sure I can retrieve the Name through the getter. This is the code I have:

```
class Classroom:

    def __init__(self):

        self.__classList = {
            001: Mark,
            002: Kevin,
            003: Stacy}
        self.currentStudent = self.__classList[001] #start at the beginning of the list

    @property
    def currentStudent(self):
        return self.__currentStudent

    @currentStudent.setter
    def currentStudent(self, ID):
        try:
            currentStudent = __classList[ID]
        except:
            print("Invalid ID entered")
```

When I went to test the code, from my understanding with using @property if I input the following:

```
classroom = Classroom()
classroom.currentStudent = 002
print(classroom.currentStudent)
```

I should have the screen print "Kevin" no?  What I am getting at the moment is the screen is printing 002.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't make an instance of `Classroom`. You're working with the class object itself, which behaves very differently.

Comment: Also, your setter is busted anyway.

Comment: `currentStudent = __classList[ID]` <-- where are you supposed to get the `__classList` from? It won't work unless you have it in the global namespace... Also, given that you're not storing it anywhere, you might as well delete the method.

Comment: @zwer so I need to declare the classList outside of the init method then?  Should it work if I do that?

Comment: @Skitzafreak - no, you need to reference the namespace of the properties you're trying to access. In your case you already have it right in the getter part, why did you forgo accessing the properties on `self` in the setter part? Also, don't use double underscore at the start of your property name unless you want it mangled with the class name it belongs to.

Comment: Why are you using double-underscores for `__classList`? Anyway, you need to go back to the basics of OOP. You are confusing instances with the class. Inside your setters, you are merely assigning some values from your `__classList` dictionary to a local variable `currentStudent` that gets discarded when the method returns to the caller, and effectively, does nothing.

Comment: @user2357112 what do you mean I didn't make an instance of Classroom? In my example 2 lines of code?  Or is there something wrong with my class as a whole. I honestly haven't programmed Python much at all :\

Comment: Where do you think you've made an instance of `Classroom`? You have a single line, `Classroom.currentStudent = 002` which is working on the *class*, and actually *removes your property* and replaces it with `002`  (which btw is no longer valid syntax in Python 3 and in Python 2 is equal to simply `2` anyway, so you should just use a string maybe).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so yes I know this isn't a great use of OOP.  The goal is to create basically a side class that can hold the dictionary and just spit out whatever the current listing is.  On full implementation it will be a rather large dictionary and I figured having one Class set up to deal with this bit would be beneficial for me in the future.
As for the instance of Classroom, It's a typo I'll fix.  Assume instead of Classroom, I had created an object of it called "classroom" that's what I meant to type out.

Comment: Also note your getter returns `return self.__currentStudent` but you've never assigned a value to `self.__currentStudent`, you always assign it to `self.currentStudent`. That will throw an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @Skitzafreak yes, OK, that's fine, but my point is you havent seemed to grok the *purpose* of a class, which is essentially to act as a template for *instances* of that class. But you never use any instances, and in your methods, you only sometimes assign to the instance (i.e. `self.something = something_else`)

Comment: As an aside, you should *never use a bare except*. I.e. `except:` Always, as much as you can, try to catch the most specific error. In this case, you should be using `except KeyError:`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What would you suggest I use instead of a class them?  What other alternatives are there for what I want to do :\

Comment: @Skitzafreak I'm not suggesting you use something else. I'm suggesting you take a step back *and learn the basics of writing classes*. A `Classroom` object that acts as a container for managing students is totally reasonable. But some of your questions like "what do you mean I didn't make an instance of Classroom?" reveal a fundamental misunderstanding of what classes *are*. Learn to walk before you run.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fair enough.  Sorry it's been a long day for me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Skitzafreak no worries. Sometimes is good to take a break for a while and return to something after you've let stuff perculate in your brain a bit. I really, really suggest you read the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html) on classes. Read and understand everything up to and including [Class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). It's really important you understand that distinction. You can worry about more advanced topics, like inheritance, later.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified it a little bit to make it work. I suppose you are using python2.7

```
class ClassRoom(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.__classList = {
            001: "Mark",
            002: "Kevin",
            003: "Stacy"}
        self.__currentStudent = self.__classList[001] #start at the beginning of the list

    @property
    def currentStudent(self):
        return self.__currentStudent

    @currentStudent.setter
    def currentStudent(self, ID):
        try:
            self.__currentStudent = self.__classList[ID]
        except:
            print("Invalid ID entered")

class_room_1 = ClassRoom()
class_room_1.currentStudent = 002
```

test

```
print class_room_1.currentStudent
Kevin
```

Comment: Having `class_room_1.currentStudent == class_room_1.currentStudent` be `False` seems confusing.